# Assign color for Raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, crop

I have a raster file that I converted I df in order to use is ggplot.
The for each pixel has its code, but R is chose colors that are not suitable for categorical variables.

So, I created as tibble with the color code

```
colors <- tibble(colors=c("000000","#ffff64","#aaf0f0","#dcf064","#c8c864","#006400","#00a000","#00a000","#285000","#788200","#8ca000","#be9600","#966400","#ffb432","#ffdcd2","#ffebaf","#00785a","#009678","#00DC82","#C31400","#FFF5D7","#0046C8","#FFFFFF"),cod_global=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220))
```

An left_joined with my df, derived from the raster, which has more about 58.000.000 rows.

I was hoping that when I plotted it and set fill as the column where I have the color codes save the software would read it assign the color to the pixels.

As it turns out, the result wasn't what I was expecting.
Here is my code and 2 images, the first one is the result without trying to assign values e the second one in when I try to assign values.

[image: without assigninvalues]

```
ggplot(Xinjiang_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = colors))
```

[image: After assigning values]

Can anyone give a hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `scale_fill_identity`.

Comment: Hi @Roland, thanks a lot for the tip. I wal able to plot color accord to my to the vector where I have the color codes. Do you happen to know what I do to make the label of the legend to take the names I have assined I another vector of the same data.frame?

Comment: I suggest you study some ggplot2 tutorials and use a proper scale instead of color values stored as data. That will make everything much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Solved as suggestion given by @Roland. I don't understand why I can't just toggle a button an close the issue.